# My formula that leaves field blank some of the time

Tags: google-sheets

I have a character sheet that puts in player skills based on their level and class.  Class and Level are cells J8 and J9 respectively.  I have a table on another sheet with all of the numbers.  There are 3 different skills, so 3 formulas  in cells G32, G33 and G44 on the sheet Ranger.  G32 and G44 both work, but G33 only works for some levels.  When levels 9,11,12,14,15,17 or 19 are selected it leaves the field blank even though all of the numbers are in the table on sheet BF Stats in D144:G163.

Any help would be appreciated.  Below is a link to the sheets.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZHKLDQFzORhvzERry2Z4Yv5WbMD6aHG8GkrV_n5AoqI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

formatting is the issue:

[image]

change the dropdown range for J9 to:

[image]

set formatting to number for whole range `D144:G163`

[image]

then change your query to:

```
=IF(J8="Ranger", QUERY('BF Stats'!$D$139:$G$163,"select E where D = "&J9,),)
=IF(J8="Ranger", QUERY('BF Stats'!$D$139:$G$163,"select F where D = "&J9,),)
=IF(J8="Ranger", QUERY('BF Stats'!$D$139:$G$163,"select G where D = "&J9,),)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't really understand what you were doing there with all the TRUE and FALSE column, but when you said it was a formatting issue, I changed the format to plain text for D144:G163 and that made it all work correctly without changing anything else.  Thanks again.